# Скрыть элемент при клике по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пытаюсь скрыть элемент block при нажатии на button, но код не работает. Скажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $("#block").css("display", "none;");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Скрыть</button>
<div id="block">Этот элемент скроется</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я увидел две проблемы:

1. Символ `;` не надо здесь:

   ```
    $("#block").css("display", "none;");
   ```

Вместо этого напишите:

```
     $("#block").css("display", "none");
```

2. Вы должны включить библиотеку JQuery.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $("#block").css("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Скрыть</button>
<div id="block">Этот элемент скроется</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас лишний символ при вызове ф-и. 
Уберите после *none* ";".

```
 <script>
    $('#button').click(function(){
       $("#block").css("display", "none");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает.

Comment: Работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

После `none` убрать `;`!

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
  $("#block").css("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="button">Скрыть</button>
<div id="block">Этот элемент скроется</div>
```